# MP3 audio stream in c# with Media Player component

Tags: c#, audio, streaming

I´m using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7 to create a tiny program to listen to a live stream over http. I realized this with the Media Player component and it works good for some minutes...

The problem is, that it stops streaming after about 4 to 5 minutes. When I press play again, the buffered stream of last 5 minutes starts to play again from the starting point.

How can I tell Media Player to continuously go on buffering the live stream for infinite time?

Answer (score 0):

For all experiencing the same problem:

I made a php file that reads the content from the stream, sets mp3 content type and outputs the stream to the file... I wanted to save bandwitdth on my streaming server by having just one connection from streaming server to php server...

**This was not a good idea!!!**

The solution for this problem was: using the original url to mp3-file on the streaming server through port 8000

That solved the problem for me on Android and on C# Media Player component.